# Code Behind No Longer finds ID tags

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I've been working on a website for several months now and am nearing my deadline.  I know my methods are a little dated.  Especially considering I still use tables.  I've actually moved in a direction away from that, but this project is being produced from an excel spreadsheet and with more than 200 fields, it seems reasonable and the person I'm creating this for was happy to see the recreation.

Nevertheless, I am having an issue where I have declared an id for an asp TableCell and am trying to assign text to it.  In the past this has worked.  Literally every other page I have built has been able to accept this code.

Initially I had a textbox named "depthSingleUnit."  With new data coming in, I realized I could combine the depth, height, and width information into one cell.  And because I don't want the user to edit this data any longer, just view the information that's already available, I dropped the idea of using a textbox and just used the tablecell to display the information.

The tablecell now has an id "dimensionsSingleUnit"

```
<asp:TableCell columnspan="1" id="dimensionsSingleUnit"></asp:TableCell>
```

The code behind reads

```
dimensionsSingleUnit.Text = PONDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ProductDimensions")
```

Yet I get the error

```
Error   3   'dimensionsSingleUnit' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. C:\Users\aking\My. Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\lampSpecs\lampSpecs\Factories\view.aspx.vb 289 4   lampSpecs
```

Am I missing something here?  I have tried changing the id.  I've tried creating a new tableCell with the same name.  Tried creating a new tableCell with a different name.  I tried creating a new file, but still have the same issue.  I've tried re-building the project.  I literally copy and paste the id into my code behind and that does not work.

The old ids from when I was using multiple cells for the data are still available, but all of the new ones that I've added will not display in intellisense and displays an error.

Comment: for an element to be accessible from code behind you need a runat="server" parameter

Comment: Seriously?  None of my other asp:TableCell elements have runat="Server" in the tags and they still work with the codebehind.  I have runat="Server for my asp:Table tag.  Let me try that though and get back to you.

Comment: I've added the runat="server" attribute to the tablecell, but the error persists.

Comment: Can you try dimensionsSingleUnit.InnerHtml = PONDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ProductDimentiond")... I've not worked with tables cells in this way normally use gridviews or repeaters. It may be that a runat="server" for the table element is enough... but usually you need it for html elements to be accessible from code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add runat="server" to your html element to get access it from code page. because only runat="server" are available on the code behind page

Answer (score 0):

Sorry meant to add as an answer....

Try

```
dimensionsSingleUnit.InnerHtml = PONDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ProductDimentiond")
```

I've not worked with tables cells in this way normally use gridviews or repeaters. It may be that a runat="server" for the table element is enough... but usually you need it for any html elements to be accessible from code

Comment: I'll give it a try.  Unfortunately, all is for not now.  I found out that last week the project was passed to someone else to carry to completion, since that individual has more time than I do to code. I was never informed.  *Sigh*

Comment: Nope.  The problem is that my code behind does not recognize anything with that id / name.  Doesn't matter whether I have runat=server in the tag either.  Intellisense does not populate the name.  In the past my coding method described above has been no issue at all.  I don't know that any of this matters though, since, as I stated in my previous comment, this project was passed to someone without my knowledge last week.  He's taking the project in a different direction and is likely starting from scratch since he prefers to code in c#.